# How can I modify emacs' Search and Replace to perform a more complicated task?

Tags: emacs, latex, auctex

total Emacs noob here. So right now I'm working on a fairly big LaTeX project in Emacs in which there are couple of places where I need to index some words, using the makeidx package. Because I also wanted indexed words to be bold, I created my own command `\ind{}` which would make the argument go bold and indexed. But right now I'm dissatisifed with this command so I'd like to change every instance of `\ind{whatever}` in my text by `\textbf{whatever}\index{whatever by default}`.

The thing is I know exactly what I want :

1. Go through the text, look for any instance of `\ind{` and replace by `\textbf{` using `search-and-replace`
2. Save the argument of `\ind` ("whatever" in this case) in memory
3. Ask me the user what should the argument of `\index` be. By default (by striking enter), it should be the first argument, but I can also change my mind and enter something different ("whatever by default" in this case). If there's no input (only a space `" "` for example) stop the program.
4. Write down `\index{`, the new argument and `}`.
5. Go to next occurance in the text.

But, alas!, I know not how to achieve this, so I need someone's help. If it should take too much time to explain how to do such a thing, would you please send me some tutorial about writing my own functions?

I hope I'm being clear, and thanks for your patience!

Comment: You can do everything but the human input bit in step 3 by using replace-regex (take a look at [link](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Regexp-Replace.html) ), so worst case you can run a regex then find the bits you wish to customize by hand...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This approach seems vaguely unorthodox to me, but it works and seems sufficient for a one-off job...

In the replacement text for `replace-regexp` and `query-replace-regexp` (<kbd>C-M-%</kbd>), one newer escape sequence is `\,(...)`, where `...` can be any Lisp expression.  There's a Lisp function `read-from-minibuffer` which reads arbitrary text typed by the user, with an optional default.  Therefore:

<kbd>C-M-%</kbd>:  Start `query-replace-regexp`.

`\\ind{\([^}]+?\)}`: The pattern to search for.

`\\textbf{\1}\\index{\,(read-from-minibuffer "index content? " \1)}`: The replacement text.  The user will be prompted for the text to put in the braces following the `\index{}` element, using the original text between the braces following the `\ind{}` element as a default.

Note that when using `query-replace-regexp`, you'll have to confirm each choice by typing <kbd>y</kbd> after each.  Use <kbd>M-x replace-regexp</kbd> if you want to avoid this step.

Answer (score 3):

Why not just redefine the `\ind` so that it can get an optional argument?

For example:

```
\newcommand{\ind}[2][]{%
  \def\first{#1}%
  \ifx\first\empty
     \textbf{#2}\index{#2}%
  \else
     \textbf{#2}\index{#1}%
  \fi
}
```

This way you can use `\ind{whatever}` or `\ind[whatever-else]{whatever}`.

Comment: Oh I didn't know this could be done, that's very nice :) But the thing is I already have 140 occurences of `\ind` and most of them _do_ need to be reformated. So I thought the quickest solution (and most elegant) would be to simply go with what I describe.

Answer (score 3):

Vlad give you the LaTeX answer to your problem. An Emacs solution is the key-macro: start with

```
C-x (
```

to define a new macro, then do one step of your change, say:

```
C-s \ind{
<left>ex
```

Then copy and paste the argument in the `\textbf` macro... You have to be careful to move in a way that will be repeatable. Once the standard modification is done, you let the cursor after the `whatever by default` and end the definition by

```
C-x )
```

now `C-x e` will call the macro you just define, letting your cursor at the correct place to change the part you want to change You can also repeat the `e` to call the macro several time at once.